# Плавающее меню для сайта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужна помощь: подскажите куда копать или где найти пример. Суть в том, что на сайте прикрепленное меню к нижней части страницы при скролле вниз нужно плавно фиксировать вверху.

Comment: это как? меню должно через всю страницу снизу вверх летать? хоть картинку приложите

Comment: я не точно написал, не плавно, а просто когда заходим на сайт меню прикреплено внизу экрана, при скролинге вверх меню фиксируется вверху

Comment: чтобы дополнить/исправить вопрос, нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Пример решения с jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="fixed-bottom">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  height: 10000px;
}
.fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
.fixed-Top {
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
     console.log(  )
        if (window.pageYOffset == 0) {

    } else {
        $('.fixed-bottom').addClass('fixed-Top');
    }
});
```

[Пример на jsFidd Клик !](https://jsfiddle.net/8a4pd57h/)